# PC keeps stuck at Ubuntu install

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an old Toshiba PC (HDD totally formatted) from DVD but install stops after a few minutes and stays stuck. What did I miss ? Partitioning HDD or something else ?

Comment: Give it a retry. Sometimes a second try is needed.

Comment: Hard to know what the problem is, can you describe what is on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Usually problems that are with installation are a per-version issue. Try either using a different Ubuntu version or try installing it from a USB drive and see if that helps. I am 95% positive this will fix it :)

Answer (score -1):

I had this once and no one could give me an answer, after lots of investigation myself, I found that the install was running out of disk space on the install and did not tell you this, it just hung. I would look in that direction if I were you.

Chris.